# Find a sequence such that $a_{2n} \leq a_{2n+2} \leq a_{2n+3} \leq a_{2n+1}$ for all $n \geq 0$ which does not converge

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence, cauchy-sequences

How to construct such a sequence? please help. thank you!

Comment: $a_n = (-1)^{n+1}$

Comment: @user284275: In your title, didn't you mean "$\ge$", not "$\le$"? Also, don't you  want some kind of boundedness (e.g., nonnegative terms)?

Comment: @quasi Replacing $\leq$ with $\geq$ changes pretty much nothing.

Comment: @Wojowu: With the current statement of the problem, any increasing unbounded sequence would be a trivial example.

Comment: @quasi No, since we want $a_{2n+3}\leq a_{2n+1}$, the sequence can't be increasing.

Comment: @Wojowu: Ah! Leave it to me to not fully read the question.

Comment: @user284275: Ignore my comment about your title -- I misread the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a sequence with *strict* inequalities, you can go for a variation on @Dark's comment above, something like
$$
(-1)^{n+1}\left(1+\frac1{n+1}\right)
$$

Answer (score 0):

Idea: if $n$ is even, choose a nondecreasing sequence (for example, constant). If $n$ is odd, choose a descreasing sequence that is bounded from below by the other one (and has a different limit). For instance, $a_n=1$ if $n$ is even, $a_n=2+\frac{1}{n}$ if $n$ is odd.